# WSO2 DAS Toolings

Tags: eclipse, wso2, wso2-das, wso2-integration-studio

I'm currently trying out wso2 DAS and I'm looking for the tooling for eclipse (Mars) as I'm already using it for ESB and registry.
I didn't figure out how to get it on wso2 website. Is someone using it or is this not existing at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tool as such for deployment.